# Cant modify results from query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose. I am doing a find query, but I am not able to modify my query results.

```
Users.find().exec((err, result) => {
   if(result){
     result.map((usr) => {
       usr.isFetchedOnce = true
     });
    console.log("user data",result); // this doesnt show isFetchedOnce
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should try this lean():

```
Users.find().lean(true).exec((err, result) => {
   if(result){
     result.map((usr) => {
       usr.isFetchedOnce = true
     });
    console.log("user data",result); // this doesnt show isFetchedOnce
  }
});
```